# PHP use preg_match_all to extract attribute names from string

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

I'm using the following code to split a string into an array of matches:

```
$text = 'text required name="first_name" label="First Name"';
preg_match_all('/"(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|[^\s"]+/', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The result is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => required
            [2] => name=
            [3] => "first_name"
            [4] => label=
            [5] => "First Name"
        )

)
```

But I need the result to be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => required
            [2] => name="first_name"
            [3] => label="First Name"
        )

)
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
preg_match_all('/="(?:\\\\.|[^\\\\"])*"|[^\s"]+/', $text, $matches);
```

Can anyone tell me where I'm going wrong? Thanks

Comment: `explode(' ',$string);`

Comment: Are you trying to use RegEx for HTML string?

Comment: The main issue I see is that `|` which implies to search for either any text that is between quotation marks or any text that is not a space or double quote.  You would be better served either by an `explode` to simply split text values or if you really need regex for whatever reason something that is similar to: `([^\s"]+(="\w*")*)`.  I'm a bit exhausted so it may not be exactly that but more or less should give you a jumping point.

Comment: @splash58: That was my first thought as well, but no it won't work because it will split label="First Name" into separate values since it has a space in

Comment: @Justinas  No, the string in my question is not HTML

Comment: `((\w+=".*?")|\w+)` - https://regex101.com/r/5b9QJO/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use pattern `/\s(?![\w\s]+\")/` in [`preg_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php) to split string by space that isn't in value.

```
$res = preg_split("/\s(?![\w\s]+\")/", $text);
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/c4JFl)

Comment: This doesn't work if there is more than one space in the value https://3v4l.org/T9CWh

Comment: @Mohammad Thanks for your help, but actually Nick is correct and this problem is not solved, it needs to work with any number of spaces

Comment: @TheBobster I can't understand problem, it work also for multiple space https://3v4l.org/ag1He

Comment: @Mohammad Ok it looks like you edited the answer and now it works with multiple spaces, so thank you!

Comment: What's about `name="first diff-name"` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `preg_match_all` here's a working code:

```
$text = 'text required name="first_name" label="First Name"';
preg_match_all('([a-zA-Z_]*[=]["][a-zA-Z_]*["]|[a-zA-Z_]*[=]["][ a-zA-Z]*["]|[a-zA-Z]+)', $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```